# How to calculate the chances of 2 chances/odds being true…?

Tags: probability, percentages

I was thinking about making a JavaScript chances percentage calculator that would combine to chances to make one… If you don’t know what I mean.. Say: 5% of the world population can solve a Rubik’s cube, and 3% of the population on earth can produce the roaring sound that is made when you yawn at any time they want. Now how do I calculate the chances in percentage that you can do both of these things? I did look for the math formula to calculate this.. however what I found was not helpful. I just want the formula to calculate the chances.
I would also like to point out that I’m probably using the incorrect words and terms to explain this.

Comment: The problem is that the events "person X can solve rubics cube" and "person X can make the desired sound at any time it wants" are not necessarily independent , so we cannot just multiply the probabilities. Without further informations , we cannot determine the ratio of people in the world who can do both.

Comment: However , those abilities are so different that assuming indepence is somewhat reasonable , but we must be careful with the result then and it should be mentioned that we assumed independence.

Comment: Please correct me if I’m wrong, but take this example: there is a 50% chance a person born can solve a cube. And there is a 50% chance that a person born can roar. (The persons born are adults in this example.) then that would mean that there is a 25% chance that a person born can both roar and solve a cube. Is that not correct?

Comment: Not necessarily. It could for example be that everyone being able to solve the cube (half of the population) has also the other ability. This also fits our assumptions , but this time we get $50$%.

Comment: I think I’m stating to understand what you’re saying. since there is a 50% chance that a persons can roar and 50% chance a persons can solve a cube, the 50% chance of a roar could always and only be true for a cube solver. So basically what you’re trying to say is that, for example: even though a coin has 50% chance to land on heads and 50% chance for tails, it could always land on heads?  That does make sense

Comment: In the coin example we can safely assume that the throws are independent (unless the coin is manipulated somehow). In particular , the coin has "no memory" , the probability for heads does not decrease if we threw heads many times. In the case with the abilities we can assume it (because it is plausible) and we can also check it more or less reliably (by counting how many people have both abilities)

Comment: But surprises are always possible see the probability of a twin birth. This has surprisingly not a universal value , but depends on several conditions.

Comment: Thank you. I do understand now. Unfortunately I was assuming that at some point both sides would have to have been the facing up side even though I do know that 50% chance only means in theory that there is a pretty good chance that both sides will win after 2 tried, I was tought in 4th grade that a 50/50 chance wold make both events true after 2 tries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Red objects: A, B, C
Triangles: A, B, D, E
Red triangles: A, B
Total objects: A, B, C, D, E

The probability that an object is red AND a triangle = $\frac{2}{5}$

$P(R\space and \space T) = P(R) \times P(T|R)$

Comment: Yes. This is what I’m trying to explain. But what’s the equation.. like if I’m using percentage. Or should I always convert percent to fraction. Or maybe decimal?

Comment: They're the same thing: $\frac{1}{2} = 50\% = 0.5$

Comment: @CohenJohnson Easiest is to use the decimal form (here $0.05$ and $0.03$) because then (assuming independence) the probabilities just multiply (here to $0.0015$).

Comment: Oh lord. It’s the morning. I knew that but I wasn’t thinking it.

Comment: Thank you for your help. This seems like it will work, but until I open the program I have yet to find out if this is the answer

Comment: @CohenJohnson, you'll need 2 pieces of information: 1) the fraction of the world population (P) that can solve the Rubik's cube ($r$)  and 2) The fraction of Rubik's cubes solvers that can roar like a lion  ($l$). So $l \times r \times P =$ the number of people that solve Rubik's cubes and can also roar like a lion.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably making the assumption that your abilities to do these two things are *independent*  --- it's as if God had sprinkled salt onto the earth, and those hit by a little salt can do Rubik's cube, while those hit by a little pepper (in a second shaking) can roar. In that case, the answer you want is this:

If $x$ percent can do the first thing, and $y$ percent can do the second, then $xy/100$ percent can do both. In your example, $x$ is $5$ and $y$ is $3$ so the answer is $\frac{15}{100}$ percent, or $0.15$ percent.

In many real situations, the things are not in fact independent. For instance, if the first thing is 'Has learned basic arithmetic' and the second is "Has studied calculus", then everyone in the second category is in the first, so if the numbers were again $5\%$ and $3\%$, the combined number would be $3\%$.

Still, for examples like the one you chose, the independence assumption is probably justified, and my formula can help you write your program.

Comment: Thank you for your help. This seems like it will work, but until I open the program I have yet to find out if this is the answer